# Google Spreadsheet and grouping similar columns

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I got a large list of skus and a list of "parent" skus. 
I want to match similar skus and list them out row.

Check the image below!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK7gq.png)

Anybody out there with spreedsheet skills out there?
(it can be excel or google sheet)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17AnkT0weoJ8VY09pckVladRUmdqJakErvNuTWXChQzQ/pubhtml?gid=60236703&single=true

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This to help you with code problems not a code writing service.

Comment: I have my column B with the formula '=UNIQUE(B2:B)' and tried to get the grouping by doing '=if(B2=D2;A2)' but then i get false on row D3, it works for one of the skus: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17AnkT0weoJ8VY09pckVladRUmdqJakErvNuTWXChQzQ/pubhtml?gid=1760322503&single=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `B2` use `=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"\d+")))`
That will extract the SKU parent id before the - and remove duplicates.

Then in C2 put `=JOIN(", ",FILTER($A$2:$A$18,REGEXMATCH($A$2:$A$18,B2)))`
That will filter all SKU's by the parent SKU in column C and join them together in a string.
That formula can then be dragged down.

If anyone knows a solution to combine the latter formula with with an array formula to avoid dragging I'm happy about suggestions.

Comment: Thats amazing! Thank you!